# C#: Razor: Convert API result to Array

Tags: .net

I am using Google Custom Search API in C#, but I have type casting errors.

```
var search_results = (Object)null; 
if (query != null && query != "")
{
   CustomsearchService customSearchService = new CustomsearchService(new Google.Apis.Services.BaseClientService.Initializer() { ApiKey = apiKey });
   Google.Apis.Customsearch.v1.CseResource.ListRequest listRequest = customSearchService.Cse.List(query);
   listRequest.Cx = searchEngineId;
   search_results = listRequest.Execute();
}

@foreach (var item in search_results.Items)
{
}

But I have compilation error in "@foreach (var item in search_results.Items)"
'object' does not contain a definition for 'Items' and no extension method 'Items' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Any idea.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var search_results = (Object)null;
```

This code should be changed to

```
Google.Apis.Customsearch.v1.Data.Search search_results = null; ;
```